# Overriding Mongo Source connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Im going to use Kafka connect to consume messages from MongoDB and publish into Kafka topic.

By default Mongo source connector creates a topic per collection. But I will have many collections and would like to have just one topic for all the collections. A message will have collection name.

1. Is it better approach to override mongo-source connector? If it so what are the things I should have keep in my mind
2. Is there any settings provided already? I know specifying `collection` as empty while creating it would listen all the collections. But it creates a topic per collection.

Comment: I believe you can use `RegexRouter` for this

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, RegexRouter helped me.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to put your answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @onecricketeer suggested I used RegexRouter. So no need to override mongo source connector to publish documents from all the collections into the same topic.

This is my configuration, It listens all the collection matching the pipeline and publishes into `mongodbTopic`

```
{
"name": "mongo-source",
"config": {
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri": "<connection_uri>",
    "topic.prefix": "",
    "pipeline": "[{\"$match\": { \"$or\": [{\"fullDocument._kind\":\"collection\"},{\"fullDocument._isInverse\":false}],\"ns.coll\": {\"$regex\": /^(.*_related)$|^(my_collection_test)$/}}}]",
    "poll.await.time.ms": 5,
    "poll.max.batch.size": 2000,
    "transforms": "dropPrefix",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": ".*",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "mongodbTopic",
    "errors.tolerance": "none",
    "copy.existing": true
    }
}
```

For more Info
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html